# Using Npgsql.NodaTime in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, npgsql, nodatime

I'm using Entity Framework Core to work with a PostgreSQL Database via Npgsql Data Provider. According to [Date/Time mapping guide](http://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/nodatime.html), NodaTime is recommended for PostgreSQL date/time mapping. In setup guide, the following code enables NodaTime type mapping:

`protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder)
{
    builder.UseNpgsql("Host=localhost;Database=test;Username=npgsql_tests;Password=npgsql_tests",
        o => o.UseNodaTime());
}`

But there is no `UseNodaTime()` extension method for `NpgsqlDbContextOptionsBuilder`. I searched `npgsql` source code but didn't find that extension method. The only one I found was `public static INpgsqlTypeMapper UseNodatime(this INpgsqlTypeMapper mapper)` in [this file](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/dev/src/Npgsql.NodaTime/NpgsqlNodatimeExtensions.cs#L42).

My `.csproj`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors" Version="2.1.0-rc1-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools" Version="2.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.1.0-rc1-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="2.1.0-rc1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.NetTopologySuite" Version="2.1.0-rc1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.NodaTime" Version="1.0.0-rc1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

`Startup.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Doko.Models;
using Doko.Filters;
using Npgsql;

namespace DokoDoko {
  public class Startup {
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) {
      Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
      services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
      services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql().AddDbContext<DokoContext>(
        options => options.UseNpgsql(
          Configuration.GetConnectionString("DokoDatabase"), 
          o => { 
            o.UseNetTopologySuite();
          }
        )
      );
      services.AddCors();
      services.AddScoped<AuthorizationFilter>();
      NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.UseNodatime();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {
      if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
      } else {
        app.UseHsts();
      }

      app.UseHttpsRedirection();
      app.UseMvc();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So whats your question?

Comment: I'm trying to do as [this code](http://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/nodatime.html#setup) but the compiler didn't find UseNodaTime() extension method.

Comment: What is the error? Are you missing any using ?

Comment: I tried `using Npgsql;`, `using Npgsql.NodaTime` but it didn't work. I have posted `Startup.cs` in my question.

Comment: Try `Install-Package NodaTime` from package manager console or search NodaTime in Nuget Package Manager and install it

Comment: Check your versions **.NETStandard 2.0** **NodaTime (>= 2.2.6)** **Npgsql (>= 4.0.0-rc1)**

Comment: I added NodaTime (2.3.0), Npgsql (4.0.0-rc1), Npgsql.NodaTime (1.0.0-rc1) and `using Npgsql; using Npgsql.NodaTime; using NodaTime;` but didn't work. I'm using .Net Core 2.1.

Comment: I have added my answer, please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to upgrade everything to the 4.0.0-rc1 version and install the [Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.NodaTime](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.NodaTime/2.1.0-rc1) package. I have reported the issue [here](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/1947)

Answer (score 4):

The documentation from the link is incorrect (the typical pre release mess). It states that you need [`Npgsql.NodaTime`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql.NodaTime) package while in fact you need [`Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.NodaTime`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.NodaTime/2.1.0-rc1) package:

```
<PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.NodaTime" Version="2.1.0-rc1" />
```

Comment: Thank you! Now the method is found.